# Implementing a higher order function that performs currying in scala

Tags: scala, currying, higher-order-functions

A coworker of mine sent me a question as follows:

> Implement a HOF(higher order function) that performs currying, the
>   signature of your function is as follows:

```
def curry[A,B,C](f:(A,B) => C) : A => B => C
```

> Similarly, implement a function that performs uncurrying as follows:

```
def uncurry[A,B,C](f:A => B => C): (A,B) => C
```

The way I understand currying is that if you have a function that takes multiple parameters, you can repeatedly apply the function to each one of the paramaters until you get the result.

So something along the lines of `f:(A,B) => C` turns into `A => f(A,_) => f(B)`????

And uncurrying would be to consolidate this application into one function as follows:

`f:A=>B=>C` would be `f(A,B)`?

Maybe I am just being confused by the syntax here but it would be great if somebody could point out what I am missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hopefully this fully worked example with a bunch of comments is easy to understand.  Please reply if you have questions.

You can execute this code by dropping it in a Scala interpreter.

```
// Here's a trait encapsulating the definition your coworker sent.
trait Given {
  def curry[A,B,C](f:(A,B) => C) : A => B => C
  def uncurry[A,B,C](f:A => B => C): (A,B) => C
}

object Impl extends Given {
  // I'm going to implement uncurry first because it's the easier of the
  // two to understand.  The bit in curly braces after the equal sign is a
  // function literal which takes two arguments and applies the to (i.e.
  // uses it as the arguments for) a function which returns a function.
  // It then passes the second argument to the returned function.
  // Finally it returns the value of the second function.
  def uncurry[A,B,C](f:A => B => C): (A,B) => C = { (a: A, b: B) => f(a)(b) }

  // The bit in curly braces after the equal sign is a function literal
  // which takes one argument and returns a new function.  I.e., curry()
  // returns a function which when called returns another function
  def curry[A,B,C](f:(A,B) => C) : A => B => C = { (a: A) => { (b: B) => f(a,b) } }
}

def add(a: Int, b: Long): Double = a.toDouble + b
val spicyAdd = Impl.curry(add)
println(spicyAdd(1)(2L)) // prints "3.0"
val increment = spicyAdd(1) // increment holds a function which takes a long and adds 1 to it.
println(increment(1L)) // prints "2.0"
val unspicedAdd = Impl.uncurry(spicyAdd)
println(unspicedAdd(4, 5L)) // prints "9.0"
```

How about a less numerical example?

```
def log(level: String, message: String) { 
  println("%s: %s".format(level, message)) 
} 
val spicyLog = Impl.curry(log) // spicyLog's type is String => Unit
val logDebug = spicyLog("debug") // This new function will always prefix the log
                                 // message with "debug".
val logWarn = spicyLog("warn") // This new function will always prefix the log 
                               // message with "warn".
logDebug("Hi, sc_ray!") // prints "debug: Hi, sc_ray!"
logWarn("Something is wrong.") // prints "warn: Something is wrong."
```

**Update**
You replied asking "How does the compiler evaluate expressions such as `a => b => f(a,b)`."  Well it doesn't.  At least the way things are defined in your coworker's snippet, that wouldn't compile.  In general, though, if you see something of the form `A => B => C` that means "a function which takes an A as an argument; it returns a function which takes a B as an argument and returns a C."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is a very pragmatic example. I am just getting all muddled up trying to think how the compiler evaluates expressions such as a => b => f(a,b)

Comment: Thanks. It's much clearer now. I am marking this as the answer.

Comment: Glad to help.  Good luck in journey learning functional programming.

Comment: @sc_ray Ah, looks like this answer did the trick. Always glad to know that one less person has one less issue grokking FP! Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure I really understand your question - what would you like to know, besides the actual implementation? As described, it should be quite trivial:

```
def curry[A,B,C](f:(A,B) => C): A => B => C = 
  a => b => f(a,b)
```

What `a => b => f(a,b)` means is, "a function of *one* argument, `a`, whose return value is `b => f(a,b)` which is again, a function of *one* argument, `b`, whose return value is what you get of you execute `f(a,b)` (whose type is `C`)"

`a => b => f(a, b)` can be written slightly more verbosely if it helps?

```
 { (a: A) => {           // a function of *one* argument, `a`
      (b: B) => {        // a function of *one* argument, `b`
         f(a, b)         // whose return value is what you get of you execute `f(a,b)` (whose type is `C`)
      }
   }
 }
```

and

```
def uncurry[A,B,C](f:A => B => C): (A,B) => C = 
  (a, b) => f(a)(b)
```

Where `(a, b) => f(a)(b)` means, "A function of *two* arguments `(a, b)`, whose return value is what you get when you first apply `a` to the HoF `f`, which returns a function that in turn consumes the `b` to return a `C`".

Does that help?

Comment: I guess I wanted to know what exactly happens when you type something as a => b => f(a,b)?

Comment: @sc_ray I hope the additional explanation helps?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am just finding this whole concept of currying rather trippy, so we have a function with multiple parameters and we are deferring the execution of the function a parameter at a time by rewriting the function as a => b => f(a,b)? How does the compiler evaluate an expression such as a => b => f(a,b)?